# How to fix menu position don't save in Laravel Voyager?

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

I have problem when I try to save menu position with drag and drop in Laravel Voyager.

Laravel 5.5 version
Voyager v1.1.3

The first image: after save сhanges his position anyway
[image]

The second image: The end result like this save, but when I press the <kbd>f5</kbd> button or update the page, this link changes position to look like the first photo.

[image]

I tried to change current link item and name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue;

Laravel 5.7 version

Voyager v1.2.6

adding `->orderBy('order')` in children method of

> \vendor\tcg\voyager\src\Models\MenuItem.php

and order functionality works again. I know it's not a proper solution but hope this will helps. Hope Voyager team will resolve this issue in upcoming release.

Comment: fixed in voyager v1.2.7 [#4186](https://github.com/the-control-group/voyager/pull/4186)